# Access member by string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I've looked high and low and maybe I am just a bit out of practice but I cannot seem to find how to do the following.

I have a String/Symbol, for example `"a"` or `:a`. The class, `B`, contains a data member, `@a`. I am looking to access the member in such a fashion:

```
def method object_of_class_B, string_or_symbol_referencing_the_member
    object_of_class_B.some_other_method string_or_symbol_referencing_the_member = 010
end
```

so I can call:

```
method c, :a
```

and have the same effect as if I had written:

```
c.a = 010
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of a solution? Did I just completely miss a key piece of Ruby in my learning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `send` to invoke the setter method like this:

```
object_of_class_B.send("#{ string_or_symbol_referencing_the_member }=", 010)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the object does not already have an accessor for the attribute, you can use [instance_variable_set](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) on the object.

For example:

```
c = SomeClass.new  
c.instance_variable_set(:@a, 'new value')
```

Comment: This only has the same effect as calling `c.a = 'new value'` if the `a=` method sets the instance variable `@a` and does nothing else. If `c` is, for example, an active record object, using instance_variable_set will not have the desired effect.

Comment: Though on second thought, the OP did say he had an instance variable @a. So never mind...

Comment: You're correct. @xuinkrbin would need to be familiar with the class he/she is 'fiddling' with.